Problems when Adding a react-konva Rectangle from Form with demo
I'd like to add new Rectangle to a Stage, when the width and the height in a form is submitted.
The addition works fine, however, the selection has a large offset, but do not understand why.
The selection is fixed when the rectangle is resized, so it must be an issue with my onSelect call.
I used the Transformer - rectangle resize - demo as a baseline.
https://konvajs.org/docs/react/Transformer.html
Here is my demo:
https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/laughing-chihiro-f448r6
Expected Rect addition:

Actual Rect addition:


Konva tells you in the console what is wrong:
Konva warning: "50" is a not valid value for "height" attribute. The value should be a number.
You can do this:
width: parseFloat(newRectangleWidth),
height: parseFloat(newRectangleHeight),

